# AWS EC2 Node.js server - 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I'm using AWS EC2 to run my node.js express server which is a window instance.

It currently has one API that returns status 200 and "success" and its listening to port 3000.

However, I keep getting a `504 Gateway Time-out` response.

I'm using the Load Balancers, the security group is setup for 443 & 80 to accept anywhere.

My target group health status is failing.

I can't even use `<PublicIPAddress>:3000` to call it from my machine.

I looked around for solution but can't seem to find the answer.

Let me know if you guys need more details.

`UPDATE`: I got it to work with just http protocol but can't seem to get it with https even though I have the target group setup and everything.

Comment: For allow traffic into node application you should have to set node port into security group also.